# Efficient DRM for Amazon app store

Tags: android, drm, amazon-appstore, piracy

I think about releasing an app at Amazon app store. They do provide their own DRM system but there seems to be no way for the app to retrieve any license validation information like Google Play offers. So I think it should be easy to patch any Amazon-DRM-protected apk file to just ignore the license validation done on the device.

My app needs communication with my server to work. On Google Play, my app retrieves LVLs license answer and sends it to my server which validates the digital signature of that answer. If it is not validated, the server just doesn't talk to the app and so makes it useless.

Is there any way to do so on Amazon app store?
What other self-implemented methods are there to protect an app?